# SQL Query not always inserting missing values

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I am writing a SQL query to update a table from another table. My goal is for my query to insert records from `table2` into `table1` if that record is not found in `table1`.

The query works great when `table1` is completely empty, but when I delete a couple records and try running my query it fails to re-insert the deleted values even though they are still in `table2`.

Here is my python code with the SQL query

```py
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table1)')
```

When I delete a record in Access from `table1` and try re running the script it does nothing, but when I delete everything from `table1` and re run the script it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `NOT EXISTS` work, assuming `col1` is primary key in the tables

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)  
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 
FROM table2  t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1)
```